# Package provided dependencies in a single zip file

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have put dependency jars in separate folder but expecting folder should be zipped instead of direct folder. I tried using assembly descriptor but it is creating separate folder with dependencies but not zipping it (folder should not be there, only zip file is expected). Please suggest me better approach to accommodate my dependency jars in a single zip file

pom.xml

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeScope>provided</includeScope>
                        <outputDirectory>/Users/venugopal/Documents/providedDependencies</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/archive_format.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal> <!-- goals == mojos -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

archive_format.xml (Assembly descriptor

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
  <id>bin</id>
  <baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>/Users/vp/Documents/providedDependencies</directory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: I need only specific scope dependencies (Provided scope) as zip

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement right, you want to package all provided dependencies into a zip file.

You are headed the wrong way using `maven-dependency-plugin`. You should use `maven-assembly-plugin` and its [`dependencySet`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet):

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
  <id>bin</id>
  <baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory>
  <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Setting the scope to `provided` will make sure only the provided dependencies are considered in this set. We need to exclude the project artifact, otherwise it will be included by default.

Comment: And above code is sample , actual project has super/parent pom.xml and having multiple webapps.Objective is all webapps provided scope moving to single zip file.Please provide details to configure parent pom.xml with assembly descriptor

Comment: Above code s working fine if only the <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>.When i try to give external location, nothing is shown

Comment: Help me to keep all my webapps jars moving in to single zip

Comment: @user439587 You can put this configuration in every child that is a war project. This way, every webapp can package the provided jar in a zip. If what you want is to package every provided dependency of every webapp into a single zip file, that you simply cannot do (by the way, what you are trying to do in the first place, packaging provided dependencies in a zip smells a lot and you are probably not doing the right thing here)

Comment: Thank you alot.If possible please suggest me the way to do all provided jars in single zip

Comment: As I said in my comment, my answer will package provided jars in a zip but it will do it on a per-project basis, so if you have 2 webapps, you will have 2 zips. If you want a single zip, it is simply **not possible** (provided dependencies are not transitive so you can't have an aggregator module)